# Common components issue in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've made 3 sets of carousel each with different API data passing into the components and a common component of the navigation button (previous and next button) I'm using to navigate but on clicking on anyone all carousel working simultaneously.

Comment: Seems they are also referencing some "common state". Please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can inspect.

Comment: Hey, you are definitely using the same state or reference for all the carousel instances on the page. Could you include some pieces of code for us to check?